# Difference in xgboost training in case of xgb.DMatrix and dgCMatrix

Tags: r, benchmarking, xgboost

Is training using data in form of `xgboost::xgb.DMatrix` faster then with `Matrix::dgCMatrix` in case of sparse data (90% of entries are zeros) on single machine with CPU ? How `xgboost` is optimized for using `xgboost::xgb.DMatrix` ?